# How to modify a file if file contain numbers that begin with '+1'

Tags: command-line, android, grep, xml

I am transferring an Android SMS database to my iPhone manually without restoring. Because of the number format of +1562... the iPhone does not recognize the format and creates a new text thread.

I am trying to change `+15629876543` to `5629876543` and `+17114747474` to `7114747474`, and so on.

There are thousands more numbers ranging in size. Any other number that has more than or less than 10 digits, should be untouched.

This seems to be a step in the right direction:

```
grep -P '(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)' file
```

retrieved from [How to grep for groups of n digits, but no more than n?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538730/how-to-grep-for-groups-of-n-digits-but-no-more-than-n)

Here is a sample of the XML file (**EDIT: I added a root element named `<root>` to make the XML *well-formed***).

```
<root>
    <sms>
        <address>+15629876543</address>
        <date>1554966601000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body> Yea, should be true. </body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments />
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>1</isMms>
        <date>1554968044000</date>
        <type>2</type>
        <mmsMsgBox>2</mmsMsgBox>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments>
            <attachment>
                <type>image/jpeg</type>
                <body></body>
                <name>Screenshot_20190411-002704_Flud.jpg</name>
            </attachment>
        </attachments>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>+15621234567</address>
        <date>1554968778000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>+17141234534</address>
        <date>1558919932000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>:)</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments />
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>+17141234567</address>
        <date>1558927846000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>It&apos;s so</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments />
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>+17145757575</address>
        <date>1543704644000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>Hey</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments />
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <date>1543704676000</date>
        <type>2</type>
        <body>More text</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments />
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>+17142323232</address>
        <date>1543704736000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>Lol not even</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments />
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>+17141010101</address>
        <date>1543704748000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>You do</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments />
    </sms>
</root>
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Are you looking for how to use sed?

Comment: Don't you mean 11 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful when using `sed` to edit XML files. (It's risky).

But you can easily use an XSLT-1.0 processor like `xsltproc` or `Saxon` to remove the leading `+1` string from the `<address>` element. So use the following XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" /> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" /> 

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="sms/address[starts-with(.,'+1')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,3)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with your XML and the result (with the XML from your question) is:

```
<root>
    <sms>
        <address>5629876543</address>
        <date>1554966601000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body> Yea, should be true. </body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments/>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>1</isMms>
        <date>1554968044000</date>
        <type>2</type>
        <mmsMsgBox>2</mmsMsgBox>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments>
            <attachment>
                <type>image/jpeg</type>
                <body/>
                <name>Screenshot_20190411-002704_Flud.jpg</name>
            </attachment>
        </attachments>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>5621234567</address>
        <date>1554968778000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>7141234534</address>
        <date>1558919932000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>:)</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments/>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>7141234567</address>
        <date>1558927846000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>It's so</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments/>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>7145757575</address>
        <date>1543704644000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>Hey</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments/>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <date>1543704676000</date>
        <type>2</type>
        <body>More text</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments/>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>7142323232</address>
        <date>1543704736000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>Lol not even</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments/>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <isMms>0</isMms>
        <address>7141010101</address>
        <date>1543704748000</date>
        <type>1</type>
        <body>You do</body>
        <mmsReaded>1</mmsReaded>
        <attachments/>
    </sms>
</root>
```

This should be as desired.

Comment: i think "DO NOT USE" is somewhat overdramatic, soul purpose of sed is to edit text.

Comment: @bac0n: Good point. I changed the introduction to something less strict.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should generally avoid using regular expressions to parse structured data. But this is a pretty simple case if you are 100% that all occurrences of `+` followed 11 digits are valid targets. You can tell `sed` to only remove `+` if it is followed by 11 numbers (I assume you meant 11 not 10, since you have 11 in your data):

```
sed -E 's/\+([0-9]{11}[^0-9]*)\b/\1/' file.xml
```

The `-E` enables extended regular expressions which give a simplified syntax and the ability to use `{N}` to mean "match N times". So here, we are matching a `+` (this needs to be escaped as `\+` since otherwise it means "match 1 or more") that is followed by exactly 11 numbers, then 0 or more non-numbers until the first [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`).

The entire match except the `+` is captured in parentheses, so `\1`, the replacement, is everything except the `+`.

---

A slightly safer approach, since all of your target numbers seem to be in `address` tags, would be:

```
sed -E 's|<address>\+([0-9]{11})<\/address>|<address>\1</address>|' file.xml
```

Or even, if your problem can be restated as "remove all `+` from lines where the first non-space string is `<address>`", you could do:

```
sed -E '/<address>+/{s/\+//}' file.xml
```